# Where to find latex configuration files on directory tree (linux)?

Tags: packages

I cannot find the exact commands to type in the terminal to find my latex configuration files and where I should put additional downloaded latex packages in case I needed them (I do not even know where they appear when you download them from the web).
I am sorry for my ignorance, but could someone help me about it?
Thank you for your attention and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tool `kpsewhich`.  On my machine I have

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

This means that my "local" TeX tree is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.  A downloaded (local in Unix parlance) LaTeX package on this machine would go into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/PACKAGE` directory.

You can find more information about the way TeX searches for files here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-530007

Comment: Thank you! If i install a package manually,should I then copy it via: `cp <package_name> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/PACKAGE` ?

Comment: You need to extract `.sty` from `.dtx` first following the installation instructions, and after installation run `mktexlsr-sys` as root

Comment: @Igotta Install manually? Bad idea. Learn first about the use of `tlmgr` and the improbable case that this is not enough, use TEXMFHOME,  not TEXMFLOCAL

Comment: @Igotta, BTW, unlike miktex, a vanilla texlive installation by default is complete. Work in your console  the command `pdflatex`? `whereis pdflatex`  pointed to the right directories? Is so, congratulations, you have already installed almost any relevant latex package in  the world.